# Formatting JavaScript using Java API

Tags: java, javascript, velocity

I am generating JavaScript code using velocity in java.

For example: I generated JavaScript and got below string:

```
importClass(java.util.ArrayList); function fun(arg) { if (true){ return true;} else{    return true;}}
```

Is there any java API that takes this String and formats this JavaScript in below manner:

```
importClass(java.util.ArrayList);

function fun(arg) { 
   if (true){ 
       return true;
   }
   else{
    return true;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260431/pretty-print-javascript-using-java

Comment: @Eloff: I went through this link and found couple of ways to format javascript. But still looking for JAVA APIs which can be directly used to format java script. Though, I can use command line option in my java code but if direct APIs are found, that will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Closure Compiler

You can use Google's *Closure Compiler*.
It formats, compresses, optimizes, and looks for mistakes in JavaScript code.

For a quick look what it can do, you can [try the web service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

---

### Example

For your example string,

```
importClass(java.util.ArrayList); function fun(arg) { if (true){ return true;} else{    return true;}}
```

if you just want to format it, use the compile options *"Whitespace only"* and *"Pretty print"*, which returns:

```
importClass(java.util.ArrayList);
function fun(arg) {
  if(true) {
    return true
  }else {
    return true
  }
}
;
```

Anyway, with Closure compiler, you have several options to optimize and/or format your input code (either given as string or file URI) and to either return the optimized/formatted JS as string or save it to a file.

I can really recommend to use the *"Simple"* optimization mode. For longer Javascripts, it really saves you lots of unneeded bytes. Plus, it speeds up script execution!

For your example string, compile options *"Simple"* (instead of *"Whitespace only"*) and *"Pretty print"* return

```
importClass(java.util.ArrayList);
function fun() {
  return!0
}
;
```

As you can see, the result of both `fun()` functions is the same (Boolean `true`).
However, the second has removed all useless code (by remaining validity!) and will be executed faster.

---

### Download & Reference

Now, the actual compiler is written in Java and is available as a [command-line utility to download](http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/files/compiler-latest.zip) (Update 2014-07-10: [New Downloadlink](http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip)).

As a second option, you could implement your own wrapper class to communicate with the REST API ([as I did for PHP](https://github.com/eyecatchup/CC_Service-php/blob/master/CC_Service.php)). Doesn't require too much effort/code.

More info is available here:
[Google Code Project Page](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/)
[Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app)
[FAQ: How do I call Closure Compiler from the Java API?](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_call_Closure_Compiler_from_the_Java_API%3F)
[REST API Reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Thanks a lot for sharing this. Let me apply this in my project and will provide the feedback.